# Proving $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{7x+7y-8}\ge3\sqrt{6}$ when $x, y, z\in [0, 5/2]$ with $xy+yz+zx+xyz=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> **Problem.** Let $x,y,z$ in $\left[0;\frac{5}{2}\right]$ such that $xy+yz+zx+xyz=4$. Prove that:
> $$\sqrt{7x+7y-8}+\sqrt{7y+7z-8}+\sqrt{7z+7x-8}\ge3\sqrt{6}.$$

The inequality was posted in [AOPS.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1743754p11345472)

I've tried to use substitution $$x=\frac{2a}{b+c},y=\frac{2b}{a+c},z=\frac{2c}{b+a}$$
and we'll prove $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{7\left(\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}\right)-4}\ge3\sqrt{3}.$$

But I don't know how to use the hypothesis $x,y,z$ in $\left[0;\frac{5}{2}\right].$

I need some hints to deal with this strange condition. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Some thoughs.**

**Fact 1.** Let $a, b, c \ge 0$ with $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2 + \frac{11}{32}a^2b^2c^2 \ge \frac{729}{4}$. Then $a + b + c \ge 3\sqrt{6}$.
(*Note*: It is verified by *Mathematica*. A human verifiable proof is needed.)

Now, let
$$a := \sqrt{7x + 7y - 8}, \quad b := \sqrt{7y  + 7z - 8}, \quad c := \sqrt{7z + 7x - 8}.$$
We need to prove that $a + b + c \ge 3\sqrt{6}$.
By Fact 1, it suffices to prove that
$$a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2 + \frac{11}{32}a^2b^2c^2 \ge \frac{729}{4}$$
or
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (7x+7y-8)(7y+7z-8) + \frac{11}{32}(7x+7y-8)(7y+7z-8)(7z+7x-8) \ge \frac{729}{4}. \tag{1}$$

If $xyz = 0$, it is easy.

In the following, assume that $xyz \ne 0$.

Let
$$u := \frac{\frac52 - x}{x}, \quad v := \frac{\frac52 - y}{y}, \quad w := \frac{\frac52 - x}{x}.$$
We have $u, v, w \ge 0$ and
$$x = \frac52\cdot \frac{1}{1 + u}, \quad y = \frac52\cdot \frac{1}{1 + v}, \quad z = \frac52\cdot \frac{1}{1 + w}.$$

Let $p = u + v + w, q = uv + vw + wu, r = uvw$.

(1) is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
 &9206\,{p}^{2}-3949\,pq-3280\,pr-3600\,{q}^{2}-896\,qr-1216\,{r}^{2}\\
 &\quad + 50328\,p-4618\,q-23059\,r+64152\\
 &\ge 0. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
The condition $xy + yz + zx + xyz = 4$ is written as
$$18p - 32q - 32r + 243 = 0. \tag{3}$$

Also, we have
$$0 \le (u-v)^2(v-w)^2(w-u)^2 = -4\,{p}^{3}r+{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+18\,pqr-4\,{q}^{3}-27\,{r}^{2}. \tag{4}$$

Thus, it suffices to prove that (2) is true for all $p, q, r \ge 0$ satisfying (3) and (4).
The rest is smooth.